# Filtering of fourier transforms of audio signals

Tags: arrays, matlab, filtering, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I have an array containing the **Fourier transform** of an input audio signal (the amplitudes corresponding to various frequencies). I wish to select specific ranges of the signal **without using the inbuilt functions**. I have performed the following simple operations for the same :

```
[audio_in,audio_freq_sampl]=audioread('F:\Signals and Systems\Take Me Home Country Roads (John Denver Cover).wav');
Length_audio=length(audio_in);
df=audio_freq_sampl/Length_audio;
frequency_audio=-audio_freq_sampl/2:df:audio_freq_sampl/2-df;
figure
FFT_audio_in=fft(audio_in);

n = length(FFT_audio_in);
init = 30000;
fin = 40000;  
conji= mod((n-init+2),n) ;
conjf= mod((n-fin+2),n) ;
fs_1(1:n) = 0.0 ;
fs_1(init:fin) = FFT_audio_in(init:fin);
fs_1(conji:conjf) = FFT_audio_in(conji:conjf);

plot(frequency_audio,abs(fs_1));
```

[image]

As we can see here, there is only one peak. the other one should be visible at the other end of the plot in the range.

The song can be found here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WF046Z5tPJE

The song must be converted to a `.wav` file before reading it.

The above code should give me a plot containing two small peaks corresponding to the ranges of frequencies - `(init , fin)` and `(conji , conjf)`. However, I am getting a peak only corresponding to the 1st range. **Both these ranges are within the size of the array - `FFT_audio_in`.**

Comment: Define _inbuilt functions_ You are using a lot of builtin functions. Also, post a reproducible example. We cannot see the graph or the peaks you refer to

Comment: Sure. There are functions developed in the 2018 version of matlab such as `bandpass`.  And yes. I will attach an example.

Comment: I have added an answer after figuring it out. I will not be accepting it though. If anyone comes up with a better way, I will be more than happy to accept their answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the following lines of code :

```
n = length(FFT_audio_in);
init = 30000;
fin = 40000;  
conji= mod((n-init+2),n) ;
conjf= mod((n-fin+2),n) ;
fs_1(1:n) = 0.0 ;
fs_1(init:fin) = FFT_audio_in(init:fin);
fs_1(conji:conjf) = FFT_audio_in(conji:conjf);
```

Turns out that in the above lines of code, conji < conjf. So in the last line of the code, I am spanning through the vector with the initial point being larger than the final point. However, with the following lines of code, this issue is resolved :

```
n = length(FFT_audio_in);
init = n/4;
fin = n/4 + 10000;  
conji= mod((n-init+2),n) ;
conjf= mod((n-fin+2),n) ;
init_2 = min(conji , conjf);
fin_2 = max(conji , conjf);
fs_1(1:n) = 0.0 ;
fs_1(init:fin) = FFT_audio_in(init:fin);
fs_1(init_2:fin_2) = FFT_audio_in(init_2:fin_2);
```

Comment: You are still using a lot of built-in functions... you initially said that you don't want to.